# Spree customization with deface, auth_shared_login_bar

Tags: themes, spree, deface

How can I move auth_shared_login_bar partial from _nav_bar to _main_nav_bar before #link_to_car?

I managed to add a login link to _main_nav_bar using this:

```
insert_before '#link-to-cart'
partial 'spree/shared/login_bar'
```

But can't find a way to remove  login bar from _nav_bar.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it:

```
<!-- replace 'code:contains("if")' -->
<!-- closing_selector 'code:contains("end")' -->
<!-- sequence :after => 'auth_shared_login_bar' -->
<%= %>
```

but I don't think it is the best way to achieve desired outcome. Any comments would be appreciated.